# ROS and Gazebo: model problems when loading joint controllers

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to control a gazebo robot using ros control but I have some problems after I load the controllers.
[This is the robot model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWbZq.png) before I load the joint controllers, the model is correct.
When I load the joint controllers I get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7B72.png), the controller.launch it's not showing errors.

Why the model implodes on the origin?

Comment: Are the initial values for the controller coincide with that of the model? If not, it might be generating some unachievable torque values for the joints and the model is behaving strangely to discount that. You can also pass the --verbose option to gazebo to print the errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the model implodes on the origin?

Most likely your SDF file is malformed. Some debugging tips:

- Inspect collisions, joints, CoM and inertia with Gazebo's GUI and see if anything looks out of place. Look out for badly place joints, overlapping collisions, extremely small / large inertias...
- Start simulation paused and step through it slowly to see if you can find out when it starts collapsing. Do this with contact visualization turned on.
- Run Gazebo in verbose mode to see if you get any useful error messages.